# regular expression for matching number

Tags: regex, linux, unix, sed, awk

I have file call phonenum.txt which contain a list of phone numbers that have been filtered from a file through procmail recipe :

```
60123456098,60135673434,60149023459,60123456334
```

Based on this file there are two conditions that need to be fulfilled in order to get their output.

1. The output must be differentiate by number 60(its the country code,so its the only constant that I can use between all the numbers) and the "," symbols in front of these number.Ex: **60135673434**..
2. What if the number 60 is in the middle of the phone number? For example: **60123456098** How can I get the output for the whole number?

Is there anyway that I can get the phone number by using match regular expression in awk or sed?

Comment: If the string only contains these phone numbers, why don't you simply split on comma?

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F, '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i~/^60/){print "phone number is ",substr($i,3)}}' your_file
```

Tested Below:

```
> cat temp
60123456098,60135673434,60149023459,60123456334,90123456789
> nawk -F, '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i~/^60/){print "phone number is ",substr($i,3)}}' temp
phone number is  123456098
phone number is  135673434
phone number is  149023459
phone number is  123456334
>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
awk -v RS="," '{gsub(/^60/,"")} 1' file
```

and if you want one line back

```
awk -v RS="," '{gsub(/^60/,"")} {printf s $0; s=","}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

How about a global substitution with `sed` using `(^|,)60`:

```
$ sed -r 's/(^|,)60/\1/g' <<< 60123456098,60135673434,60149023459,60123456334 
123456098,135673434,149023459,123456334
```

Regexplanation:

```
s/          # Substitution 
(^|,)       # Match start of the line or comma (captured)
60          # Followed by the literal 60 
/           # Replace with
\1          # Captured group (put back the comma) 
/g          # Global flag
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ grep -oP '(?<=\b60)\d+' <<< "60123456098,60135673434,60149023459,60123456334"
123456098
135673434
149023459
123456334
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/^60//;s/,60/\n/g;P;D' file
```